# Is it possible to cache Spring's Application Context between classes?

Tags: spring, gradle, junit, spring-test, applicationcontext

I'm trying to improve the performance of the Spring integration tests of a project I'm working on. We're using Spring + Gradle + JUnit.

With this configuration inside the `build.gradle` file:

```
test {
    useJUnit()
    setForkEvery(0)
    setMaxParallelForks(1)
}
```

We're able to run all tests in a single JVM. Though I think this is the default behaviour.

But I've been reading about [Spring Test Context Caching](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching) and with this property in my application-test.yml:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        test:
          context:
            cache: DEBUG
```

I noticed the following logs for test methods running in the same class

```
2017-09-05 08:33:11.829 DEBUG 5764 --- [    Test worker] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [THIS HAD SENSITIVE DATA]
2017-09-05 08:33:11.830 DEBUG 5764 --- [    Test worker] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@572e81e7 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 0, missCount = 1]
2017-09-05 08:33:11.849 DEBUG 5764 --- [    Test worker] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [THIS HAD SENSITIVE DATA]
2017-09-05 08:33:11.850 DEBUG 5764 --- [    Test worker] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@572e81e7 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 1, missCount = 1]
```

There are many more lines that say `Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key...`.

For tests methods running in other classes, I noticed similar logs, for example:

```
2017-09-05 08:33:12.971 DEBUG 10288 --- [    Test worker] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Storing ApplicationContext in cache under key [THIS HAD SENSITIVE DATA]
2017-09-05 08:33:12.971 DEBUG 10288 --- [    Test worker] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@2dad6721 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 0, missCount = 1]
2017-09-05 08:33:13.194 DEBUG 10288 --- [    Test worker] c.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate : Retrieved ApplicationContext from cache with key [THIS HAD SENSITIVE DATA]
2017-09-05 08:33:13.194 DEBUG 10288 --- [    Test worker] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@2dad6721 size = 1, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 1, missCount = 1]
```

Both classes are annotated equally:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles({"default", "profile-1", "profile-2"})
public class SomeControllerTest {

    // Test methods...
}
```

And I think it should be possible for test methods in both classes to share the same `ApplicationContext` thus decreasing the amount of time the tests last for. But, is it possible to do that? If so, how?

I noticed both `ApplicationContext` objects are stored in the cache at around the same time `08:33:11.829` and `08:33:12.971`. Does the Test Runner execute the tests in different threads or something?

Comment: Are you by any chance using `@MockBean` or `@SpyBean`?

Comment: We are not using `@SpyBean`, but we are using some `@MockBean` annotations which are different between different controller test classes... Do you think that's the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your contexts are in fact cached, but you effectively have two different contexts since you use Spring Boot's `@MockBean` feature.

The use of `@MockBean` causes each `ApplicationContext` to have a different *unique key* under which it is stored in the context cache.

Although this may not be publicly documented anywhere, there is in fact in-line documentation in the implementation of `org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizerFactory`:

> We gather the explicit mock definitions here since they form part of the MergedContextConfiguration key. Different mocks need to have a different key.

I have opened an issue against Spring Boot to have this behavior documented: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10182

Comment: I thought of that `@MockBean` will create separate context, but what if I am using `@SpyBean` ??? Sholdnt it work then?

Comment: In my case, classes with `@MockBean` or `@SpyBean` causes context to be not shared at all!